# How to use OpenTK.GLControl for Gtk# application

Tags: c#, monodevelop, opentk

I want to use OpenTK library for my little GUI Gtk# application. I know, that I should include OpenTK.dll to Windows.Forms project and than I should include GLControl to toolbox and  use it. But I can't do it in the MonoDevelop and Gtk.Window project, because I can't find GlControl after included OpenTK.dll! I can run and change OpenTK Sample Console application, but how can I use it in my application? Can anybody explain to me how can I use OpenTK and GLControl in Gtk.Window application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778875/how-to-render-using-opentk-glwidget-in-monodevelop) SO link will help? Have a look at the discussion and the code, it's bound to get you started. CHEERS!